# Do not want to display the row index column in the dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo

I used a dojox.grid.DataGrid to render a table. I also included dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector in the first column. I saw there is always a column named Row rendered between the checkbox column and the actual data column.

Could you please let me know how do I not to have this Row index column rendered?  Is there any flag I can set when creating the structure?  Or is there any field I need to remove?

Thanks a lot.

=========================================

```
dojo
        .ready(function() {
            var myDojolayout = [
                    {
                        type : "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector"
                    },
                    // Now include the data cells in a view occupying the rest of the grid.
                    [
                            new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({
                                width : "10%"
                            }),
                            {
                                name : "Summary",
                                fields : [ "firstName", "lastName",
                                        "companyName", "phone", "email" ],
                                editable : true,
                                width : "10%",
                                formatter : function(fields) {
                                    var first = fields[0], last = fields[1], notes = fields[2], phone = fields[3], email = fields[4];
                                    return first + " " + last + "<br>"
                                            + companyName + "<br>" + phone
                                            + "<br>" + email;
                                }
                            }

                    ] ]

            var mygrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                id : "gridId",
                store : store,
                autowidth : "true",
                rowselector : "15px",
                keepRows : "30",
                rowsPerPage : "10",
                style : "height:300px",
                structure : myDojolayout
            }, "gridContainer");
            mygrid.startup();
            dojo.connect(mygrid, "onApplyEdit", function(row) {
                store.
```

Comment: Isn't this a result of your layout having 

new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({
                                width : "10%"
                            })

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the responses.  I removed that line new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({width : "10%"      }), but that column still shows up.  Any other solutions? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by replacing your layout with the following.  Some of the fields may not work because they're implementation specific, however I do not see a rowIndex or anything like that after these changes.

```
 var myDojolayout = [
                {
                    type : "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector"
                },
                // Now include the data cells in a view occupying the rest of the grid.

                        { cells: [{
                            name : "Summary",
                            fields : [ "firstName", "lastName",
                                    "companyName", "phone", "email" ],
                            editable : true,
                            width : "500px",
                            formatter : function(fields) {
                                var first = fields[0], last = fields[1], notes = fields[2], phone = fields[3], email = fields[4],companyName= fields[5];
                                return first + " " + last + "<br>"
                                        + companyName + "<br>" + phone
                                        + "<br>" + email;
                            }}]
                        }

                ];
```